# Emacs regex search for lines with less then 20 characters

Tags: regex, emacs

So if we have some txt file with variable line length, how to search with emacs regex lines with fewer of some number (let say 20) of characters.

Comment: Do you have anything yet?

Comment: searching for lines with more than some number of characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job it matches any line with between 0 and 20 tokens on it

`^[^\n]{0,20}$`

`^` Start of a line (or String)

`[^\n]` Anything that is not a new line

`{0,20}` The previous between 0 and 20 times

`$` End of line (or String)

Comment: Rolled back radical 3rd party edit - change suggestions of that sort should be posted as comment (or if sufficiently different as their own answer) rather than as a change to someone else's proposed answer.

Comment: To clarify, josifoski's first comment is the *correct* answer. B8vrede's answer matches any line beginning with a character other than `\ ` or `n`, and followed by (ending with) the literal sequence `{0,20}`. Nothing wrong with up-voting for pointing in the right direction, but I'm not sure it should have been accepted.